# Dúvida com Triângulo de Floyd

Tags: javascript

Estou com um problema neste código:

```js
function calculate() {
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var x = input;
  for (var i = input; i > 1; i--) {
    x += i;
  }
  var j = 1;
  var k = 1;
  var number = 1;
  var output;
  while (k < x) {
    output = number.toString() + " ";
    number += 1;
    if (number = j) {
      output += "\n";
      j = 1;
      k++;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="number" />
<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button><br/>
<span id="output"></span>
```

Ele sempre retorna 1. Alguém pode, por favor, me ajudar?

Comment: Por que não edita a pergunta e descreve o que o código deveria fazer?

Comment: `if (number == j)`  ao invés de `if(number = j)` você está testando e não atribuindo... E ainda assim, você possui um loop infinito em seu algoritmo, faça um teste de mesa.

Comment: Depois veja que a solução é muito mais simples https://www.rushis.com/floyds-triangle-javascript-code/

Comment: O valor digitado no `input` irá definir oq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input id="input" type="number" />
<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button><br/>
<span id="output"></span>

<script>
function calculate() {

var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
var x = input;


  var string;
  var increm=1;
  var i;

for(i=0;i<x;i++){
  string = "";

  var j=0;

  while(j<= i){
        output += string + "    " + increm;
        j++;
        increm++;
}
output+= "<br>";
}

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Por favor, explique sua resposta. O que é trivial para você, pode não ser para os outros.